# Sencha - Conditionally adding namesapce in requires

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I have a requirement that I want to add namespaces in `requires` conditionally.

e.g. In below example I want to add 'views.popupgrid' name space on specific condition. Currently it's always loaded.

```
requires: ['Ext.window.MessageBox','views.popupgrid','user.MyUser'  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Conditional dependencies are not supported by the Sencha toolchain. While you would be able to write in a text editor of your choice

```
requires:[
    (location.hash=='#test')?'testpopup':'normalpopup'
]
```

and this would work in the uncompiled version, Sencha Cmd would not be able to compile it correctly, and would throw errors.

Therefore, Sencha Architect does not support this syntax.

What you can do, while staying Standards-compliant: you can use [`Ext.Loader.loadScript`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.Loader.html#method-loadScript), e.g. like this:

```
Ext.define('MyForm',{
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel'
    initComponent:function() {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);
        if(x==3) Ext.Loader.loadScript({
            url:'MyCustomFormComponent.js',
            onLoad:function(){
                me.add({
                    xtype:'mycustomformcomponent'
                });
            })
        });
    }
})
```

Please note that in this case you will always have to deliver `MyCustomFormComponent.js` alongside the minified `app.js`, because the dependency cannot be resolved by the toolchain. Also, depending on the connection, there may be a visible delay before the resource is loaded and the component is added to the form.

It is usually faster and smoother to always load the dependency, especially if you intend to deliver the app as a single minified javascript file (e.g. using Sencha Cmd).